# convert pthread to objective-c

Tags: objective-c, c, pthreads

Im trying to convert the following to `objective-c` code.

This is the current thread I have in `C` and works fine

```
//calling EnrollThread method on a thread in C
pthread_t thread_id; 
pthread_create( &thread_id, NULL, EnrollThread, pParams );

//What the EnrollThread method structure looks like in C
void* EnrollThread( void *arg )
```

What my method structure looks like now that I've changed it to objective-c

```
-(void)enrollThreadWithParams:(LPBIOPERPARAMS)params;
```

Now I'm not sure how to call this `objective-c` method with the `pthread_create` call.
I've tried something like this:

```
pthread_create( &thread_id, NULL, [refToSelf enrollThreadWithParams:pParams], pParams );
```

But I believe I have it wrong. Can anyone enlighten me on why this does not work and what it is I need to do to fix it so that I can create my thread in the background? My UI is getting locked until the method finishes what it's doing.

I was thinking of also using `dispatch_sync` but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Check out the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html), focusing on dispatch queues (also known as Grand Central Dispatch, GCD) or operation queues (e.g. `NSOperationQueue`). But that guide makes the case for using dispatch or operation queues in lieu of threads.

Comment: so dispatch/operations are different to threads @Rob?

Comment: dispatch queues and operation queues use threads behind the scenes, but provides a much simpler interface. Much, much easier to do concurrent programming with these queues.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the explanation. I ended up going for the `dispatch_async` approach as it seemed to be better for multitasking applications on a mac.

Comment: I think GCD is a wonderful place to start (though I think it might be incorrect to categorically state that it's better than operation queues, as each has their own respective advantages). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In objective C you don't really use `pthread_create`, although you can still use it, but the thread entry point needs to be a C function, so I'm not sure if this would be the best approach.

There are many options, as you can read in the [Threading](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) and [Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) documents.

- `performSelectorInBackground` method of NSObject (and subclasses)
- `dispatch_async` (not `dispatch_sync` as you mentioned)
- NSOperation and NSOperationQueue
- NSThread class

I would suggest giving it a shot to the first one, since it is the easiest, and very straightforward, also the second one is very easy because you don't have to create external objects, you just place inline the code to be executed in parallel.

Comment: So when I do something like this: `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(enrollThreadWithParams:) withObject:(__bridge id)(pParams)];
` I get an bad access error. I assume im not calling my method properly using the `performSelectorInBackground` method. I'll have a further look into it.

Comment: I went for the `dispatch_async` approach, it was very easy to get it up and running, and my UI/UX  is no longer locked. My program does crash if I try to run the same queue twice (if I press the button twice which invokes the same thread two times in a row). Is there anything I need to watch out for when dealing with `dispatch_async`?

Comment: @Pavan The obvious aspect to consider is **synchronization**. That depends a little bit on the target queue that you're using. With a serial queue you would have less problems than a parallel queue. I guess you must have a little bug somewhere.

Comment: For now, I've disabled the button that dispatches the thread after the first time its called, and enabling the button again once the thread has finished. I didn't understand your comment about it being dependent on the 'target queue' that I'm using.

Comment: @Pavan The `dispatch_async` function takes a `dispatch queue` as a first argument, this can be a serial or a parallel queue. Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async)

Answer (score 1):

The go to reference for concurrent programming is the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html) which walks you through dispatch queues (known as Grand Central Dispatch, GCD) and operation queues. Both are incredibly easy to use and offer their own respective advantages.

In their simplest forms, both of these are pretty easy to use. As others have pointed out, the process for creating a dispatch queue and then dispatching something to that queue is:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domain.app", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // something to do in the background
});
```

The operation queue equivalent is:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // something to do in the background
}];
```

Personally, I prefer operation queues where:

- I need controlled/limited concurrency (i.e. I'm going to dispatch a bunch of things to that queue and I want them to run concurrent with respect to not only the main queue, but also with respect to each other, but I don't want more than a few of those running simultaneously). A good example would be when doing concurrent network requests, where you want them running concurrently (because you get huge performance benefit) but you generally don't want more than four of them running at any given time). With an operation queue, one can specify `maxConcurrentOperationCount` whereas this tougher to do with GCD.
- I need fine level of control over dependencies. For example, I'm going to start operations A, B, C, D, and E, but B is dependent on A (i.e. B shouldn't start before A finishes), D is dependent upon C, and E is dependent upon both B and D finishing.
- I need to enjoy concurrency on tasks that, themselves, run asynchronously. Operations offer a fine degree of control over what determines when the operation is to be declared as `isFinished` with the use of `NSOperation` subclass that uses "concurrent operations". A common example is the network operation which, if you use the delegate-based implementation, runs asynchronously, but you still want to use operations to control the flow of one to the next. The very nice networking library, AFNetworking, for example, uses operations extensively, for this reason.

On the other hand, GCD is great for simple one-off asynchronous tasks (because you can avail yourself of built-in "global queues", freeing yourself from making your own queue), serial queues for synchronizing access to some shared resource, dispatch sources like timers, signaling between threads with semaphores, etc. GCD is generally where people get started with concurrent programming in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch.

Bottom line, I personally use operation queues for application-level asynchronous operations (network queues, image processing queues, etc.), where the degree of concurrency becomes and important issue). I tend to use GCD for lower-level stuff or quick and simple stuff. GCD (with `dispatch_async`) is a great place to start as you dip your toe into the ocean of concurrent programming, so go for it.

There are two things I'd encourage you to be aware of, regardless of which of these two technologies you use:

1. First, remember that (in iOS at least) you always want to do user interface tasks on the main queue. So the common patterns are:

   ```
   dispatch_async(queue, ^{
       // do something slow here

       // when done, update the UI and model objects on the main queue

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           // UI and model updates can go here
       });
   });
   ```

   or

   ```
   [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
       // do something slow here

       // when done, update the UI and model objects on the main queue

       [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
           // do UI and model updates here
       }];
   }];
   ```
2. The other important issue to consider is synchronization and "thread-safety". (See the [Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) section of the *Threading Programming Guide.*) You want to make sure that you don't, for example, have the main thread populating some table view while, at the same time, some background queue is changing the data used by that table view at the same time. You want to make sure that while any given thread is using some model object or other shared resource, that another thread isn't mutating it, leaving it in some inconsistent state.

There's too much to cover in the world of concurrent programming. The WWDC videos (including 2011 and 2012) offer some great background on GCD and asynchronous programming patterns, so make sure you avail yourself of that great resource.

Comment: Hey Rob, I truly appreciate answers like these, it reminds me of when I give extensive breakdowns with code samples for other people so that they can really understand whats going on and how to apply  it in future projects, so thank you. I found the numbered list to be particularly helpful in understanding how to handle slow and main queues together. I have a few questions: 1. You mentioned that what you wrote applied to "iOS atleast", would the same be applied to cocoa? 2. Could you give various examples for where A must finish before B then > C sort of concurrency would be applicable too?

Comment: cont... and 3. Near the bottom you mentioned that user-interface tasks should be executed on the main queue. In my case, I have a biometric application integrated with hardware system setup, where I disable controls before I capture the fingerprint from the device, this capturing of fingerprints is done in 5 successive frame captures with messages sent to the user when they should lift and place their fingers on the device. Between each frame the `NSImageView` is updated, this locks the main queue.. thats why I've pushed the fingerprint capturing & updating the image in the BG, is this bad?

Comment: @Pavan Let's move this to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50205/convert-pthread-to-objective-c-conversation-with-pavan

Answer (score 0):

If you already have working code, there is no reason to abandon pthreads.  You should be able to use it just fine.

If, however, you want an alternative, but you want to keep your existing pthread entry point, you can do this easily enough...

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("EnrollThread", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    EnrollThread(parms);
});
```